# Toolbar text size in Android Support Library 22.2.1 vs 22.2.0

Tags: android-support-library, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

Yet another question based on [Chris Banes's cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) demo.

After updating to the latest release of the library, I couldn't help notice an outstanding difference in the toolbar text size, when it is not collapsed.

Previous release, 22.2.0:
[image: design support library 22.2.0]
Current release, 22.2.1:
[image: design support library 22.2.1]

What's the reason for such an increase and most importantly how do I override it?

Is it easily achievable to set the desired size by using an xml attribute, or does a specific style need to be defined & used?

**Note**

Whichever the solution is, it shall not affect the size of the text when the toolbar is collapsed. Only when it is expanded, like in the above screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a custom style for CollapsingToolbarLayout:

```
<style name="CustomToolbar">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/expanded_title_size</item>
</style>
```

And then apply it using **[setExpandedTitleTextAppearance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(int))** method:

```
myCollapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CustomToolbar);
```

Comment: short and concise, exactly what I was looking for. thanks !